# PHP-Jquery image upload not working

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to post form data through ajax

**form1.php**

I use request to get all URL parameter data

```
$_REQUEST["Ename"];
$_REQUEST["eImg"];
```

To upload the image,i use this code http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

In the above link,you can see the source code,in the place of $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];,i use $_FILES['image']['name']; but it is not uploading the file and giving success message.

```
include('db.php');
session_start();
$session_id='1'; // User session id
$path = "uploads/";
```

I removed script that is marked with **

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
    **if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {**

$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
if(strlen($name)) {
  list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
  if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
    if($size<(1024*1024)) { // Image size max 1 Mb
      $actual_image_name = time().$session_id.".".$ext;
      $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image='$actual_image_name' WHERE uid='$session_id'");
        echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview'>";
      } else {
        echo "failed";
      } 
    } else {
      echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Invalid file format.."; 
  }
}  **else {
  echo "Please select image..!";
  exit();
}**
```

Comment: Your javascript is not the same as in the tutorial...they use `.ajaxForm()` and you use `.ajax()`.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder:I've written my own jquery only used their PHP upload script.

Comment: And that's likely why it doesn't work. Use their javascript. Yours doesn't submit the file properly.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder:They show preview,i do not want that,when i echo my request,i get the file name.What's wrong in my jquery script

Comment: @PhpMyCoder:Can you correct my jquery script.

Comment: That is what's wrong with your script. PHP doesn't need the filename. It can't magically use the filename to grab the file off a client's system. The client needs to upload the file to PHP. Is there an option to disable the preview? It seems like their jQuery is the way to go.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder:How do i add name field to that jquery script.

Comment: As the answer and I have suggested: use `$.ajaxForm()`

Answer (score 1):

you simply *can't* upload files via [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

you'll have to use some trycky iframe-stuff or something like that to make this work. luckily, there are ready-to-go plugins for jquery to handle this for you (like [`$.ajaxForm()`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for example wich seems to be the one that's used in the tutorial you're reading).

**EDIT:**
the plugin also allows to add extra data thats not present in the form itself. to quote [the documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object):

> **data**
>   An object containing extra data that should be submitted along with the form.
>
> ```
> data: { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }
> ```

Comment: :I've few other fields in my form.How id i send the data throught that plug in,i've mentioned here.

Comment: they used an action for the form, because this _isn't_ "real" ajax. **you can't upload files via ajax**. what this plugin does is submitting the form to a hidden iframe and get the response from there, so **it just looks like ajax** but isn't.

Comment: i'm going to give up. again: file-upload via ajax isn't possible. you have to use another solution wich is clearly described in the tutorial you've posted as well as in the documentation of the plugin used by the tutorial: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Answer (score 1):

For upload image by ajax you should use an iframe and set its id to form target.

Please have a look at
http://www.coursesweb.net/ajax/upload-images

It is very simple code to upload image

Answer (score 0):

That won't work! 
Images are handled differently from the text data in Ajax so you would have to do more than just post it using the $.ajax({}) method.

You can however use the jquery.form.js plugin it works perfect http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#download there is a tutorial on how to use it 
[here](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html)

Any ways I have used it my self so let me elaborate for you.

**The JavaScript code is here**

```
$('.uploadForm').live('click', function(evt){   
     $('#feedback').html(' ');
     $('#feedback').html('<img src="images/loader_image.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
     $("#formID").ajaxForm({
           target: '#feedback'
           }).submit();
    evt.preventDefault();   
 });
```

If your PHP code is fine this should work .....
Just post the rest of the form fields in the normal way way
This should work for you. If the PHP code is fine

For example if you had other form fields like firstname and lastname  in form like this one

```
<div class="form">
 <fieldset class="ui-corner-all">
   <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" align="center">Client information</h3>
     <form action="save_new_client.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="clientForm" method="POST">
     <label>First Name</label>

      <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" class="required" minlength="3"/>
      <label>Lastname</label>
      <input name="date_added" type="text" id="date_added" class="dateEst" />
       <label>Image</label>
       <input name="photo" type="file" id="photo" />

      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Save" class="uploadForm"/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input type="reset" name="reset" id="button" value="Cancel" /></td>
   </form>
 </fieldset>
<div id="feedback"></div>
</div>
```

Below it you'll just need to add a div or paragraph to hold your feedback message  ....
then the rest will be just fine (like I said if your PHP code is okay)I have not looked through it alot

Comment: You don't have to worry about the other fields, they will be serialized and posted normally like other ordinary forms.

Comment: :I do not want to show preview,i looked at the malsup,i'm not clear ,how to add my form fields to that script.Can you  tell me ,how i do that in the here link.

Comment: That's easy remove the preview from the PHP code and replace it with a success message

Comment: :Will this submit the form or submitting the data is through is ajax.

Comment: it will submit the form data and image through Ajax .... just follow this tutorial and eliminate the preview .....<a href="http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html">Here</a> or just look at the edits I have made to my first answer

Comment: :This code will go to save_new_client.php.I'm trying to do it with ajax,it should not go to action to post data,it should be clientForm,if i click submit,data should be posted in ajax.

Comment: It will not go there, if you can see in the JavaScript there is    evt.preventDefault(); This means you will remain on the same page and get your feedback message in the div ("feedback")

Comment: :Thanks a lot,you've been helping me a lot.You've used id as upload form,feedback in JS,i do not see them in html,Do i need to change them.

Comment: You've used id as upload form,feedback in JS,i do not see them in html,Do i need to change them.

Comment: They are their check at the bottom  .... There is a div with id "feedback" it holds the message after submission of the form and also the loading state .... then I used class on the button  class="uploadForm" because all my forms are using the same script. You can chose to use id="uploadForm" then you will use the id selector $("#uploadForm") in JS

Comment: Your code is submitting data to save_new_client.php.Can you test your code in localhost.I saw the 9lessons and under stood,i use like you only but it goes to save_new_client.php

Comment: you could be having some bugs in the javaScript code use firebug or the Google chrome developer tools.