# ajax not uploading file pic to database and server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My problem is that my script doesnt upload the pic on serv and insert it into database when i use ajax submit for some reason. If i submit form with php action="file.php" it works. Here are my ajax script and php one.I dont see where the problem is and why it works with php submit and not working with ajax. Thnx in advance.

```
<script>
$(function() {
//twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: "engine/app/process.php",
        data: $(\'form.edit\').serialize(),
        dataType:\'json\',
            success: function(data){
                    $("#bday").html(data.a)
                     $("#locatie").html(data.b)
                     $("#descriere").html(data.c)
                     $("#interes").html(data.d)
                     $("#status").html(data.e)
                     $(".img").html(data.f)

                   $("#myModal").modal(\'hide\');    
                },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
            }
              });
    });
});
</script>
```

php script

```
<?php
require_once('../core/dbconfig.php');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$nume=$_POST['nume'];
$bday=$_POST['bday'];
$locatie=$_POST['locatie'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$interese=$_POST['interese'];
$despre=$_POST['descriere'];
$id_user=$_POST['id_user'];

$query="Update `users` SET username='$nume',bday='$bday',Locatie='$locatie',Relatie='$status',Interese='$interese',Descriere='$despre' where id='$id_user' ";   
                                $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die("query failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));


$path = '../../images/users/'.$id_user.'/'; 
if(!is_dir($path)){
  mkdir($path,0755);
}
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg", "JPG");

            $name = $_FILES['img1']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['img1']['size'];


            if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {
                    if($size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            /*$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;*/
                            $actual_image_name=$id_user.'.'.$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                                {
                                $queryz="Insert into Galerie (ID_User,Poza,Poza_Profil) VALUES ('$id_user','$actual_image_name',1)";    
                                $resultz=mysqli_query($dbc,$queryz) or die("query failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));                              
                                }
                            else
                                echo "failed";
                        }
                        else
                        echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                        }
                        else
                        echo "Invalid file format..";   
                }   



echo json_encode(array("a" => $bday, "b" => $locatie,"c" => $despre,"d" => $interese,"e" => $name,"f" => ""));
?>
```

Comment: Simple ajax function doesn't work for file uploads. Refer posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116766/php-jquery-image-upload-not-working?rq=1 for more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With only Ajax request you can't upload the file to the server. A Better option is use [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

This links also includes some example codes, follow the documentation and achieve what you want.

Take a look how to implement `jQuery Form` plugin, on [Ajax based image upload](http://webomnizz.com/blog/jquery/ajax-based-instant-image-upload/)

Comment: Thnx, i added one more script for upload image. Coudnt modify mine i'm not that good at ajax and i wanted to keep the json return too. But it works with 2 scripts too so thnx for help :).`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
      target:  \'#preview \'
  })
   });
 
</script>`

Comment: @Downvoters may i know what is the reason for down vote here?

Answer (score 1):

The serialize method puts your form fields data in a string complying to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type used to submit forms to servers for processing, while files are submitted in requests encoded in the multipart/form-data content type, so, serialize ignores file inputs.

You should use formData

```
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('your_frm_id'));
var file = document.getElementById('img1').files[0];
    if (file) {
        $('#sent_progress').show();
        form.append('img1', file);
    }
```

In ajax use

```
data: form,
```

Read More here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Or you can use some Jquery Plugin to upload your file with form
hope it will help

Comment: thnx, it was good info but i couldnt modify my script and i just made new one for upload image. So practicly on 1 submit i call 2 functions one for normal infos and 1 for upload :)